# How To Enable NFS v2 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nfs

I use Ubuntu Linux and NFS to move files to an embedded Linux system. The Linux on the embedded board requires NFS v2 which is not enabled on 18.04. It is not practical to update the embedded Linux.

How do I go about enabling NFS v2 on my 18.04LTS system? The same process works perfectly when I use an older Ubuntu 14.04 computer. It reports NFS v2 as enabled where 18.04LTS shows it as disabled.

The articles I am finding so far regarding configuration do not mention enabling the older version.

Answer (score 1):

Its unclear exactly what you are asking. If you want to know how to install NFS thats simply `sudo apt install nfs-common`

Are you asking how to MOUNT via nfs version 2? nfs-common has the ability to mount previous versions of NFS by specifying that during mount for example:

```
sudo mount -t nfs localhost:/storage/backups/git_home_dir /mnt -o nfsvers=2

# type the mount command to see what is mounted

mount

localhost:/storage/backups/git_home_dir on /mnt type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=2,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp6,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=::1,mountvers=1,mountport=50822,mountproto=udp6,local_lock=none,addr=::1)
```

EDIT: Now I understand (my servers that have been upgraded from 16.04 did not have this issue)

You need to edit `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` and add or edit the line

```
RPCNFSDOPTS="--nfs-version 2,3,4
```

Then restart the kernel-server

Comment: When I enter the command: sudo cat /proc/fs/nfsd/versions

18.04 indicates -2 +3 +4 +4.1 +4.2 (v2 is disabled)
14.04 indicates +2 +3 +4 +4.1 +4.2 (v2 is enabled)

I'm trying to figure out how to enable v2 for 18.04LTS

Comment: edited with an update to my original comment