# How To Enable NFS v2 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nfs

Much like the following question:
[How To Enable NFS v2 on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193536/how-to-enable-nfs-v2-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I want to enable nfs version 2 protocols for some uboot stuff which only supports version 2 of the NFS protocols. As far as I can tell, version 2 of the protocol should be supported by the kernel I have compiled.

```
 cat /boot/config-5.15.0-1037-raspi | grep -i nfs
# CONFIG_USB_FUNCTIONFS is not set
CONFIG_KERNFS=y
CONFIG_NFS_FS=m
CONFIG_NFS_V2=m
CONFIG_NFS_V3=m
CONFIG_NFS_V3_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFS_V4=m
CONFIG_NFS_SWAP=y
CONFIG_NFS_V4_1=y
CONFIG_NFS_V4_2=y
CONFIG_PNFS_FILE_LAYOUT=m
CONFIG_PNFS_BLOCK=m
CONFIG_PNFS_FLEXFILE_LAYOUT=m
CONFIG_NFS_V4_1_IMPLEMENTATION_ID_DOMAIN="kernel.org"
CONFIG_NFS_V4_1_MIGRATION=y
CONFIG_NFS_V4_SECURITY_LABEL=y
CONFIG_NFS_FSCACHE=y
# CONFIG_NFS_USE_LEGACY_DNS is not set
CONFIG_NFS_USE_KERNEL_DNS=y
CONFIG_NFS_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_NFS_DISABLE_UDP_SUPPORT=y
# CONFIG_NFS_V4_2_READ_PLUS is not set
CONFIG_NFSD=m
CONFIG_NFSD_V2_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V3=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V3_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V4=y
CONFIG_NFSD_PNFS=y
CONFIG_NFSD_BLOCKLAYOUT=y
CONFIG_NFSD_SCSILAYOUT=y
CONFIG_NFSD_FLEXFILELAYOUT=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V4_2_INTER_SSC=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V4_SECURITY_LABEL=y
CONFIG_NFS_ACL_SUPPORT=m
CONFIG_NFS_COMMON=y
CONFIG_NFS_V4_2_SSC_HELPER=y
```

I've tried adding `--nfs-version 2,3,4` to multiple locations in `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` but to no avail... What am I missing? How does one enable nfs version 2 protocols on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Maybe this post solves the problem. https://askubuntu.com/a/1470251/764025